# Always process only the latest message (per key) in real-time processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When consuming a Kafka topic, Kafka will deliver all messages to the consumer in order. Now assuming the data in a topic is real-time data where only the latest message for each key matters, i.e. all previous messages of the same key could be considered stale (think of e.g. stock prices).

**At times when processing is slower than the rate of production, is there an elegant way to ignore all previous messages for the key and just process the latest one?**

In the sequence diagram below, that would be at `2. consume`, where there are 2 messages of *key1* waiting.

My strong hunch is that this is not (elegantly) possible, because processing of messages happens at the partition level. If so, **would it perhaps be possible if I guaranteed a 1:1 mapping key:partition, e.g. through the use of a custom partitioner?**

In other words, the problem would change from "process only latest message of every key" to "process only latest message of every partition". (Whether it's a good idea to have thousands of partitions to be able to do this, is another question...)

**I am interested in answers for plain `Consumer`s as well as Kafka Streams PAPI and DSL**

[image: example]

Comment: Similar to the recommendation of ksqlDB, alternative solutions like Druid or Clickhouse offer Kafka ingest patterns, however, consumer lag will always be a thing, so you cannot accurately guarantee what you're querying is actually up to date with "wall time"

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for pointing out alternatives. I had a brief look at Druid, and it seems it is made for ad-hoc-queries, rather than continuous queries, triggered by real-time data. I guess the simplest, albeit not necessarily cheapest, way to address my problem is to scale out so much that there is no lag, as Iraj suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is not about Kafka but rather the stream processing concepts. This statement:

> the data in a topic is real-time data where only the latest message for each critical matters

*The state of the world at any time is created by applying every single event one after another*. Even though some events in the middle are not changing the state and could, in theory, be ignored, you must visit them.

In your case, you wouldn't know which messages of "key1" is the latest unless you start from the beginning and scan through the end. In streaming, the term "end" means NOW, which moves as time passes. So, when you design your real-time application using Kafka as the underlying message bus, you should **consider that you must process all the messages in the order they are produced**. Some data might be garbage or outdated.

If your **consumer is slower than your producer**, consider adding more partitions to increase parallelism to avoid building backlogs.

At the end, if you insist on this application, you can always consider **KSQL**. It does the same thing you are asking for by maintaining a state and keeping only the latest message for each key. *It is not a plain consumer streaming application*

Comment: Thanks. I guess your ksqlDB solution would mean a decoupling of a) maintaining the last state (in a table) and b) processing by polling (?) the table for changes. Or perhaps one can subscribe to changes of the table, and then look at the latest value? This part is not fully clear to me yet. Btw I guess Kafka Streams KTable could be used for this as well...

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Kafka Streams and KTable are already integrated. If possible, you can even convert your logic to a KSQL. There have been great features in the KTables recently that you might have your solution out of the box. I know there was a lot of work around online analytics. Just take a look. Let me know if you need help in that area. This is an advanced use case :)